# How can I get the value inside the xml tag?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am trying to get the value of xml file.

```
<p1>
    <cts>Pq44</cts>
    <cts>qw44</cts>
</p1>
```

`P1.JAVA`

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class P1 {
    private List<Cts> cts;

     public P1() {
         cts = new ArrayList<cts>();
     }  
     public List<cts> getcts() {
        return cts;
     }
     public void setcts(List<cts> cts) {
        this.cts = cts;
     }
}
```

`CTS.JAVA`

```
public class CTS {

    private String ct;

    // Getter and setter for ct.

}
```

My `Main.java`

```
try {            
    File file = new File("D:\\Bye.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(P1.class);

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    P1 p = (P1) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    List<CTS> cts =  p.getCTS();
    // Size of list coming right `2`
    for (CTS c : cts) {
          System.out.println(CTS2.getCT());
    }
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run main.java, it prints:

```
null
null
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have done some work around. I am posting my  Code which will work on based XML file.

**p1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p1>
    <cts>Pq44</cts>
    <cts>qw44</cts>
</p1>
```

**P1.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "p1")
public class P1 {

    private ArrayList<String> cts;
    public ArrayList<String> getCts() {
        return cts;
    }
    public void setCts(ArrayList<String> cts) {
        this.cts = cts;
    }
}
```

**TestApp.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JAXBException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        String filePath = ".\\p1.xml";

        File file = new File(filePath);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(P1.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        P1 p = (P1) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        List<String> cts =  p.getCts();
        // Size of list coming right `2`
        for (String c : cts) {
              System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

try this way it will work fine.

**output**

```
Hello World!
Pq44
qw44
```

Comment: You don't need to do your workaround.  By leveraging the `@XmlValue` annotation you could use the object model from your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13989888/383861

Answer (score 1):

I think your loop should look like

```
for (CTS c : cts) {
    System.out.println(c.getCt());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@XmlValue` and do the following:

**CTS**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CTS {

    @XmlValue
    private String ct;

    public String getCt() {
        return ct;
    }

    public void setCt(String ct) {
        this.ct = ct;
    }

}
```

**P1**

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class P1 {

    private List<CTS> cts;

    public P1() {
        cts = new ArrayList<CTS>();
    }

    public List<CTS> getCts() {
        return cts;
    }

    public void setCts(List<CTS> cts) {
        this.cts = cts;
    }

}
```

**p1.xml**

```
<p1>
    <cts>Pq44</cts>
    <cts>qw44</cts>
</p1>
```

**App**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws JAXBException
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        String filePath = ".\\p1.xml";

        File file = new File(filePath);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(P1.class);

        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        P1 p = (P1) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        List<CTS> cts =  p.getCts();
        // Size of list coming right `2`
        for (CTS c : cts) {
              System.out.println(c.getCt());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Hello World!
Pq44
qw44
```